# Which is the shortest path to share a secret between people?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

My problem looks like a secret sharing problem. That’s to say:

We have N people. Each of those owns a word to share to other people.
The aim is that all people know all the words of other participants.
People can only discuss in houses. There are H houses. Each of those may only accept a limit of L members. In a house, all members share their word to others. 
We assume that:

- People can only say their word (thus, they may not share words they learnt from other people).
- The words never change.

I want to answer the question: For all participants, what is the shortest path (from house to house) to learn all words?

Solution with L=3, N=5 and H=2, let’s call H1 the house number 1 and H2 the house number 2 :

- Member 2 : H2 -> H1 -> H1
- Member 3 : H2 -> H2 -> H2
- Member 4 : H1 -> H2 -> H1
- Member 5 : H1 -> H1 -> H2

Does this “secret sharing” problem refer to well-known algorithms?

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, no i don't want you to give me the solution but only well known algorithm I may refer to. In fact this is a problem I was asked to solve during an interview. I tried constraint programming, but I can't find the procedural way to obtain a solution. That's why I posted this question on the forum.